# Calculate a div's height with jQuery - minus header and footer

Tags: jquery

I'm using a sticky footer (negative margin solution) and it works fine. What I need to do is calculate the window's height, subtract the known height of the header and footer then apply that number and use it for the height of the main wrapper div. CSS solutions cause other issues, is there a good way to do this?

This is my rough idea:

```
var h = window.height();
var k = 300; //header is 100px footer is 200px
$('#wrap').height(h-k);
```

Comment: You can't write `300px` in JavaScript. Drop the `px`.

Comment: What do you mean  CSS solutions cause other issues, what issues?

Comment: Sorry bout that, got it squared away now... any better idea how to do this?

Comment: `$('#wrap').height($(window).height() - 300`)

Comment: adding display:table to the parent and display:table-cell to the child that needs to stretch is screwing up the SASS grid im using.

Comment: @Mifeng - perfect. Can't accept answer as a comment though, want to give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea:

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
var k = 300;
$('#wrap').height(h-k);
```

However, I'd recommend doing this in CSS as doing this in JavaScript without a specific reason is bad form.

Comment: I completely understand and somewhat agree, but situations dictate solutions... not much I can do here and not enough space to describe the mess of css I inherited.

Answer (score 2):

Just rewrite my comment into ans. This is what I do usually:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        var height = $(window).height();
        var k = 112;

        $('#sidebar').height(height - k);

    }).trigger("resize");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was on the right track, as rrowland and Mifeng pointed out. After a little more digging I was able to come up with this, which suited my needs perfectly. Thanks for the push guys!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var callback = function () {
     var h = $(window).height();
     var k = 112;
     $('#sidebar').height(h-k);
  };
  $(document).ready(callback);
  $(window).resize(callback);
</script>
```